# Differential linear equation first order?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the equation $(1+y^2)\,dx+(xy+1)\,dy=0$.
It is a linear differential equation of the first order.
Now the problem is that this doesnt have the regular form of this type of equations which is $$\frac{dy}{dx}+p(x)y=q(x) \ .$$
I know I can divide both sides by $dx$ and then I'll have $(1+y^2) +
(xy+1)y'=0.$ Still, it should be $(xy+1)+y'$ not $(xy+1)y'$.

Comment: It is linear for $x$ as a function of $y$, not the other way 'round.

Answer (score 4):

If you set $M(x,y)=(1+y^2),~~N(x,y)=xy+1$, you see that $$M_y=2y,~~N_x=y$$ and $$\frac{M_y-N_x}{-M}=\frac{-y}{1+y^2}$$ is a function respect to $y$. Now think of an integrating factor $\mu(y)$ and then make your OE exact.

Comment: ..•¤*Excellent*¤•..@Babak S. シ

Comment: @flashdesign2550: $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Babak you are awesome :)

Comment: Indeed, awesome!! $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks for saying so. I saw you are full, and cannot make additional plus :-)